# Alternative to loading stylesheet into head

Tags: javascript, css

Can anyone tell me what is the alternative of loading stylesheet into head when we are trying  to load stylesheet dynamically and how can i do it?

Comment: Check this http://www.csstutorial.net/css_misc_inserting.php

Comment: $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">');

Comment: @VinodVT, none of these options answer the OP's question.

Comment: @daR, you're assuming the OP is using jQuery. Also, if you're confident of an answer, just post it as an answer instead of a comment. OP can't approve comments, so if your input solved the OP's problem, you will not get the credit. #protip

Comment: Thanks everyone, actually what i wanted to ask is not to append the stylesheet in head instead I wanted it to append it in a test harness div which i was using. Sorry for not being so clear, although i have got the solution i seek.

Answer (score 0):

You can load them dynamically. See [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

There are different implementations for this (you can Google, "load css dynamically", but the basic principle is the same: using JavaScript, you create a `link` element, give it the appropriate attributes, and append it to the head.

Here's a simple example taken from:
http://otaqui.com/blog/1263/simple-script-to-load-css-from-javascript/

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
link = document.createElement('link');
link.type = 'text/css';
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.href = url;
head.appendChild(link);
```

---

Here's a more complex, but robust example, taken from the [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) library.
https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/blob/master/plugins/yepnope.css.js

This solution allows for a callback *(after you load the CSS, do this...)*

Answer (score 0):

another alternative is using jquery, try this:

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">');
```

hope it helps :)